# Geocoding API sending inconsistent results

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have consumed Google GeoCoding APIs in one of my Project and encountered that for a particular address its results are inconsistent.
Sometimes it sends single result and sometimes multiple results for the same address.
Could you please confirm whether it is Google's GeoCoding normal behavior?

I have executed the readyAPI script as mentioned below and found inconsistency with "100 E Shore Dr US 60404" address.

Get- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=address&key=GoogleKey
Below is the code for ReadyAPI Script:

log.info("Address passed")

log.info address

log.info ("formatted address by Google")

log.info formattedaddress

log.info("response by Google")

log.info response

log.info("partial match in case of Range Interpolated")

log.info partialmatch

**result output:**

**Result 1:**

Thu Nov 08 13:12:49 IST 2018: INFO: 100 E Shore Dr US 60404

Thu Nov 08 13:12:49 IST 2018: INFO: formatted address

Thu Nov 08 13:12:49 IST 2018: INFO: Joliet, IL 60404, USA

Thu Nov 08 13:12:49 IST 2018: INFO: partial match

Thu Nov 08 13:12:49 IST 2018: INFO: true

Thu Nov 08 13:12:49 IST 2018: INFO: response

Thu Nov 08 13:12:49 IST 2018: INFO: APPROXIMATE

**Result 2:**

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO: Address

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO: 100 E Shore Dr US 60404

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO: formatted address

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO: 100 E Walton St, Chicago, IL 60611, USA

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO: partial match

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO:

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO: response

Thu Nov 08 13:13:14 IST 2018: INFO: ROOFTOP

Comment: Hard to say. Would you mind posting a request that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @xomena: Could you please look into this and suggest me on the same. 

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you are getting two different results and none of them is compliant with the initial search string '100 E Shore Dr US 60404'.

First of all you should provide a search string in format that is used by official postal service in the USA. In your example you are missing locality name, so the address is incomplete and it may lead to different unexpected results in Geocoding API.

Have a look at suggestions in the Google Maps Platform FAQ:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat

According to the USPS.com the complete address should be '100 EASTSHORE DR
SHOREWOOD IL 60404'.

[image]

So if I search this address in Geocoding API I get result '100 Eastshore Dr, Shorewood, IL 60404, USA' as expected

You can see it in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D100%2520EASTSHORE%2520DR%2520%2520SHOREWOOD%2520IL%252060404

[image]

I hope this helps!